# Add a div class css to a javascript function automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have hardcoded two values which display a green icon on the one which has online status and red icon on the one which is offline. Now i want it to automatically add the green icon in the table when my function is called.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
          <table class="table table-bordered table striped " id="thinker_table" >
          <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th>Thinker Name</th>
                <th>MAC Address</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Indicator</th>
                <th>Show Routines</th>
                <th>Show Devices</th>
                </thead>


              </tr>
                <td>IPLConference Room</td>
                <td>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
                <td >Online</td>
                <td>
                <div class="led-green"></div>
                <td> <input type="button"  value="Click Here" onclick="window.open('RoutineDetails.php','popUpWindow','height=500,width=700,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');"></td>             
                <td> <input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="window.open('DeviceDetails.php','popUpWindow','height=500,width=800,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');"></td>   
                <tr>
                <td>Host_34F60E </td>
                <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                <td >Offline</td>
                <td>
                <div class="led-red"></div>

                </td>

                <tfoot >
              <tr>
                <th>Thinker Name</th>
                <th>MAC Address</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                </tfoot >
          </table>
        </div>

</div>

</div>
```

This is my javascript below im displaying the result in a table. the table should display a green icon where the status = 1. As my condition is if status = 1 hence i should get green icon on all the table row.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("test.json", function(data){
     var thinker_data = '';
     $.each(data.data, function(key, value){
      if(value.status == "1")
      {
        thinker_data += '<tr>';
        thinker_data += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
        thinker_data += '<td>'+value.mac+'</td>';
        thinker_data += '<td>'+value.status+ '</td>';
        thinker_data += '</tr>';   
      }

     });
     $('#thinker_table').append(thinker_data);

    }); 
  });

  </script>
```

The answer was helpful but now now i am getting the icon like this
[image: Icons are not centered]

also how do I add the two buttons as well in the table?

Comment: The way this site works generally is ask the entire question at once or if you find yourself editing the question to add new question(s) as a NEW question with a link to this one.

Comment: Sorry for the hassel an you please help me

Comment: 1. FIX the malformed invalid HTML.2. then use that with the code you have tried in a NEW question, people will try to help you, be clear in what you have tried to do and exactly what you wish to have as a result.

Comment: Note here how I edited your unanswered question to illustrate how better to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54441134/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure I understand the question, but from what I've read, you want to display a green circle if the user has status=1. And you get that information from a json file.

Well you need to create the circles in css first!

**Css:**

```
.online {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background:green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
.offline {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background:red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Then, when you create a new row, you had the "online" class to the column you want:

```
 $.each(data.data, function(key, value){
  if(value.status == "1")
  {
    thinker_data += '<tr>';
    thinker_data += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
    thinker_data += '<td>'+value.mac+'</td>';
    thinker_data += '<td class="online"></td>';
    thinker_data += '<td></td>' //to make the "Indicator" column space
    thinker_data += '<td> <input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="window.open(\'RoutineDetails.php\',\'popUpWindow\',\'height=500,width=700,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes\');"></td><td> <input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="window.open(\'DeviceDetails.php\',\'popUpWindow\',\'height=500,width=800,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes\');"></td>'
    thinker_data += '</tr>';   
  }

 });
```

Do note I've created a sample input because I do not have access to the "test.json" file.

Check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4xe6nfL/2/) for a working example.

If you also wan't a red circle for status=0, use the offline class!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var thinker_data = '';
  let data = {
    "data": [{
      "name": "text",
      "mac": "SOMETHIN5239321",
      "status": "1"
    }, {
      "name": "tex2t",
      "mac": "S23THIN5239321",
      "status": "1"
    }]
  };
  $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
    if (value.status == "1") {
      thinker_data += '<tr>';
      thinker_data += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>';
      thinker_data += '<td>' + value.mac + '</td>';
      thinker_data += '<td class="online"></td>';
      thinker_data += '<td></td>' //to make the "Indicator" column space
      thinker_data += '<td> <input type="button" value=\Click Here" onclick="window.open(\'RoutineDetails.php\',\'popUpWindow\',\'height=500,width=700,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes\');"></td><td> <input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="window.open(\'DeviceDetails.php\',\'popUpWindow\',\'height=500,width=800,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes\');"></td>';
      thinker_data += '</tr>';
    }

  });
  $('#thinker_table').append(thinker_data);
});
```

```css
.online {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.offline {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <table class="table table-bordered table striped " id="thinker_table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>Thinker Name</th>
        <th>MAC Address</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Indicator</th>
        <th>Show Routines</th>
        <th>Show Devices</th>


      </tr>
    </thead>
    <td>IPLConference Room</td>
    <td>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
    <td>Online</td>
    <td>
      <div class="led-green"></div>
      <td> <input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="window.open('RoutineDetails.php','popUpWindow','height=500,width=700,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');"></td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="window.open('DeviceDetails.php','popUpWindow','height=500,width=800,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');"></td>
      <tr>
        <td>Host_34F60E </td>
        <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
        <td>Offline</td>
        <td>
          <div class="led-red"></div>

        </td>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Thinker Name</th>
            <th>MAC Address</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
I've edited the code and the snippet to repeat your buttons in every column. I think this is not the best solution, but you're not being very clear on what's your goal/what's your evironment.

Comment: I could not think of how to write the class which was simple as this.

thinker_data += '<td class="online"></td>';

Comment: How do i call the button function as well here in the javascript

Comment: added the snippet from the fiddle to make it all-inclusive as an answer.

Comment: Thank you! @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: What do you mean @arslaanmalik ? I've seen your edit, but I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Bro now i want to copy the buttons in the table just like we did the led. Buttons are created above

Answer (score -1):

I'm don't entirely follow the chain of events in this question, and where you are at now, but from what I gather you want to know how you can add buttons into your table with valid function calls onClick?

*I prefer to use template strings when writing out html in javascript and just interpolating variables. Looks very clean*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("test.json", function(data){
     var thinker_data = '';
     $.each(data.data, function(key, value){
      if(value.status == "1")
      {
        thinker_data += `
          <tr>
            <td>${value.name}</td>
            <td>${value.mac}</td>
            <td>${value.status}</td>
            <td>
              <button onClick="location.href='https://www.example.com'">Click Me</button>
            </td>
            <td>/* Or an interpolated url in case it should be dynamic */</td>
            <td>
              <button onClick="location.href='${interpolatedUrl}'">Click Me</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        `;
      }

     });
     $('#thinker_table').append(thinker_data);

    }); 
  });

  </script>
```

Comment: So your saying i should use event handlers? like create an even onclick that would run the function.? 

How do i do that. I just want buttons to be shown and the button should just go to the location.link specified

Comment: Oh I see, then my example can be simplified by using either `<a href="https://www.example.com">Click Me</a>`. This link would not look like a button however, unless you used Bootstrap, or wrote some CSS to style it as a button yourself. Alternatively, you could keep the button onClick methodology, and just replace the javascript called on click: `<button onClick="location.href = 'https://www.example.com'">Click Me</button>`

Comment: "Looks very clean" - I tend to disagree myself when it moves to a more complex set of elements/html, but that is just my opinion - all that white space gets injected into the page etc.  But again IMHO only.

Comment: To each their own, I suppose I should have added an "IMO" disclaimer 
Usually I'm more concerned with making my Javascript look tidy rather than the html of my page as I spend more time working in scripts than surfing DOM nodes.